# Case-preserving search and replace in vim?

Tags: vim, search, replace, case-sensitivity

In `vim`, I know I can search with or without case sensitivity. But if I want to search for a string in either upper or lower case, and replace it with a replacement of the same case, is that possible in a single `:s///`?

For example, I want to change these lines:

```
short
Short
SHORT
```

to

```
long
Long
LONG
```

I can do this in three `:s` commands, or one insensitive `:s` and go fix the cases manually, but is there a better way?  A case-preserving search and replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a native feature of `:s` that does this as far as I know, but if you're willing to install add-ons, you could look at Michael Geddes' [keepcase plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=6).

Answer (score 7):

You can try this plugin.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish

This plugin can help you to match not just the case sensitive text, also its variants too.
Like `/good{,ies}` will match both good as well as goodies.

Similarly, it can replace with case sensitive as well as variant included.

```
      :%S/long/short/g
```

will replace long with short, Long with Short, LONG with SHORT.